# Two cards are drawn from a poker deck without replacement.

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn from a regular deck of 52 poker cards one by one without replacement. Find the probability such that second card drawn is of higher in rank than the first card?(Ranks in increasing order can be taken from Ace to King) .

Comment: You should clarify whether in comparing two cards, their ranks may be equal or one must always be "higher in rank".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except from the case when ranks are equal, in half of the cases first card has higher rank than second card and in half of the cases second card has higher rank than the first card. So let's find the probability of having the same rank first:

If I understand the question correctly, we are drawing the cards in order. So whatever we draw in the first turn doesn't matter. In the second turn, probability of having the same rank as the first card is $\frac{3}{51} = \frac{1}{17}$. So, the probability of having cards with different ranks is $\frac{16}{17}$. As stated above, in the half of these probabilities, the second card will have a higher rank so the answer is $\frac{8}{17}$.